# NetBeans C++: Linker Can't Find External Libraries Specified in Linker Options

Tags: c++, mingw, linker-errors, netbeans-8

I've been trying to learn how to use NetBeans as a C++ development environment. I installed NetBeans 8.2, installed MinGW, and compiled a simple *Hello World* program to make sure everything works. I then decided to try to compiler an old OpenGL project (based on [this tutorial](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Table-of-Contents.html)) that I had up-and-running in Visual Studio. Unfortunately, I keep getting errors saying the linker can't find the glew32 or glut32 library files:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglew32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglut32
```

As best as I can tell, however, I've set all of the necessary linker options;
[screen-shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoKSD.png).

What am I missing here?

---

My project's compile command as stated in the output pane:

```
g++ -o dist/Debug/MinGW32-Windows/opengl_tutorial build/Debug/MinGW32-Windows/nbproject/Main.o build/Debug/MinGW32-Windows/nbproject/ReadTGA.o -L\"C\:/C++\ Libraries/glew-1.13.0/lib/Release/Win32\" -L\"C\:/MinGW/lib\" -L\"C\:/C++\ Libraries/glut-3.7/lib\" -lglew32 -lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32
```

---

### Things I've Tried

- Removing spaces from external libraries' file path.
- Placing .lib files in MinGW's lib folder (this gets rid of the original error and results in a slew of undefined reference errors).
- Adding each library's bin folder to the *Aditional Library Directories* list and adding the DLLs to the *Libraries* list.
- Switching between putting the file paths in the *Aditional Library Directories* list in quotes and not putting them in quotes (without quotes I get undefined reference errors).

**Additional System Information**

- Operating System: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP1
- Processor: 2GHz Intel Pentium Dual-Core

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding environmental variables in
Properties->Run->Environment

In my case

Name=LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Value=/usr/local/apps/Java/jdk-14/lib:/usr/local/apps/root6.22.02Install/lib/root:/Work/Soft/general_classes/lib (and some more paths which no need to be pasted here)